# Check `type` of bson field to determine if it's a $numberDecimal (mongo/node)

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, bson

I'm working with a mongo aggregate pipeline result. I need to convert Decimal128 values to numbers. E.g.

```
amount: { $numberDecimal: '200' } <-- dont want
amount: 200 // <-- desired format
```

The tricky part is I want to recursively check every property and only if it is a decimal, then change it to a number. So my question is, what is the best way to determine if the bson object is a NumberDecimal? I was able to achieve this by first calling

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))  

// Before parsing:
// Decimal128 {_bsontype: 'Decimal128', bytes: <Buffer 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3c 30> }
// After parsing:
// amount: { $numberDecimal: '200' }
```

then checking if each object has a `$numberDecimal` property, and if it does then calling `Number()` on the value. Overall this just seems like a round-a-bout way to achieve this.

Is there a better way that doesn't involve parsing the object and looking for the $numberDecimal key; I expected I would be able to do something like check the typeof or instanceof the bson object, but it is just `object`:(

Here is my function (which works) but I feel there must be a better way than checking for the $numberDecimal key.

```js
  const recursivelyMutateNumDec = (object) => {
    const jsonObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
    for (const k in (jsonObj)) {
      if (typeof jsonObj[k] === 'object' && jsonObj[k] !== null) {
        if (jsonObj[k]?.$numberDecimal) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
          jsonObj[k] = Number(object[k]);
        } else recursivelyMutateNumDec(jsonObj[k]);
      }
    }
    return jsonObj;
  };
```

Appreciate any insight/suggestions!

Comment: Check the type with `instanceof` not `typeof`

Comment: I guess I don't know what to compare it to for instanceof, e.g. `(object[k] instanceof ?)`?
Logging the constructor for one of these objects shows: 
`<ref *1> [Function: Decimal128] {
fromString: [Function (anonymous)],
Decimal128: [Circular *1]
}` but I'm not really sure where I would get `Decimal128` from in order to use it for comparison in instanceof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Decimal128](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/blob/95e8293f95b6fff65a37962b05cebf40f0cb6a41/src/decimal128.ts#L122) is a BSON type. If you import it:

```
const { Decimal128 }  = require('bson');
```

You can check the type in your code as following:

```
if (object[k] instanceof Decimal128) {
```